# How to fetch data from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to fetch the dish name from menu table based on the restaurantID in the restaurant table. Mt database structure:
[image]

Being new to firebase, I'm not able to find the starting point on how to query through the data.

Comment: restaurants  and  menu both have different table, Am I right?

Comment: From your above structure it seems clear that your resraurant id of restaurant table is same as your menu id of menu table.

Comment: Yes.. restaurant and menu are 2 different tables.. restaurantID generated in restaurant table is related to the menu table.. restaurantID and dishID are different

Comment: can you provide a code which gives you restaurants id ?

Comment: You have add one field in `restaurants id` in every `dishes`.And `restaurants id` is string that contain multiple restaurants ids just like this  `restaurant1,restaurant2,`.

Comment: What you have done? anything?

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932786

Comment: What is the key `-LxSiDXHCXM7pMDdwPJA`? Is this a user ID? How do you get it's value?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Add one field in restaurants id in every dishes.
Then create the `Class model` for `Dish`.

Now fetch dish data from  Firebase.

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
List<Dish_Model> list=new ArrayList();
mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           Dish_Model dish= postSnapshot.getValue(Dish_Model.class);
           list.add(dish);// here you will get All dish data from firebase
       }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
 });
```

At last You need filter data as per `restaurants id`
Suppose you have `String  restaurants_id="xcnvkncxvkjnxj"`.
Create list for restaurant dishes

```
  List<Dish_Model> restaurant_dishes=new ArrayList();
  for(Dish_Model  dish:list)
   {
    String[] separated = restaurants_id.split(",");
       for (String id:separated )
         {
           if(id==restaurants_id)
              {
               /*if current dish contain restaurants id then dish will add in 
                  restaurant dishes*/
               restaurant_dishes.add(dish);
                break;
                /*then we break the loop bcoz same dish will not have multiple same 
                 restaurants_id*/
               }
         }
    }
```

That's done. `restaurant_dishes` contain all the dishes of `restaurant`.